# How to set application information

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, pkg-file

I am developing an app using the `Qt Nokia SDK`.
I have googled and searched forums, but I can't seem to find anything about how to set application version.

I'm wrapping the `sis` file using the `Nokia smart installer`, so I would also like the information to pop up when I'm using the smart installer.

I guess I have to edit the `.pro` file, but I don't know what to insert to be able to set the application version, application name, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default a display name for your application is derived from the `TARGET` variable value in your .pro file. This display name is used e.g. in menu grid and SIS installation package. To change it, use the `DEPLOYMENT.display_name` .pro file variable:

```
DEPLOYMENT.display_name = My Great Qt App
```

If memory serves me well, the installataion package version number is derived from the `VERSION` variable:

```
 VERSION = 1.2.3
```

Further reading: [qmake variable reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-variable-reference.html)